# setState of an array to the values of another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data structure:

```
        this.state = {
        client: {
            abilities: [],
        },
        abilitiesDisplay: [],
```

and I am trying to set state of the client abilities empty array to abilitiesDisplay array, which has been mutated in the code and now has two items.

My set state function is as follows:

EDIT: the client and abilitiesDisplay are declared earlier in the function:

```
    const {
        client,
        abilitiesDisplay
    } = this.state;


           this.setState(() => ({
                client: {
                    ...this.state.client,
                    abilities: [
                        ...client.abilities,
                        abilitiesDisplay
                    ],
                }
            }))
```

The set state is not working in this case and client.abilities is still and empty array. Is the error obvious?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value You need to use `state.client`

Comment: @SLaks: thank you, could you elaborate? use it where?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Your second code snippet refers to variables named `client` and `abilitiesDisplay` without showing their declarations nor initializations.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: thank you for the comment, I have updated the code block

Comment: What are the values of `client.abilities` and `abiaitiesDisplay`?

Comment: client.abilities is an empty array, and abilitiesDisplay was mutated in render and now is an array of two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the elements of the `abilitiesDisplay` array to the `client.abilities` array, you can create a new array that contains all the elements in both arrays by spreading them both.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    client: {
      abilities: ["baz"]
    },
    abilitiesDisplay: ["foo", "bar"]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        client: {
          abilities: [
            ...previousState.client.abilities,
            ...previousState.abilitiesDisplay
          ]
        }
      }));
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, Tholle: not overwrite, just add to it. but since it's empty at the start, is there a way to just add elements of abilitiesDisplay to it?

Comment: @ksenia You're welcome! Ah, I misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately ran the code and abilitiesDisplay is an array of two elements and client.abilities is just empty []

Comment: @ksenia I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't it work like you intended if you press "Run the snippet"? It doesn't matter if one of the arrays are empty, it will still work.

Comment: unfortunately not, but this seems to work client: this.setState(() => ({ {...this.state.client, ...client.abilities.push(abilitiesDisplay)}})). Unfortunately it creates an array of one index with the array of two inside. :D Do you know how to get rid of this array to just have an array of two?

Comment: @ksenia Don't use push. That will mutate the state. Sorry, are you saying my example is broken? I don't understand. Are you really spreading both arrays?

Comment: no, no, your example is not broken, it works when I run the code snippet, it's my example that's broken

Comment: this.setState((prevState) => ({
    client: {
     abilities: [
      ...prevState.client.abilities,
      ...prevState.abilitiesDisplay
     ]
    }
   }), function callback() {
    console.log("client.abilities", client.abilities);
    this.props.updateClient(client, this.props.client.id);
   })

Comment: abilitiesDisplay is an array of two and "client.abilities" is still []

Comment: @ksenia `client.abilities` is a reference to the old array. Write `this.client.abilities` to get the new one instead.

Comment: oh wow! that really did work, thank you! But where I pass the client object to the redux updateClient endpoint, it's not updated. this.setState((prevState) => ({
    client: {
     abilities: [
      ...prevState.client.abilities,
      ...prevState.abilitiesDisplay
     ]
    }
   }), function callback() {
    this.props.updateClient(client, this.props.client.id);
    console.log("client is", client);
   })

Comment: @ksenia Great! You're welcome. Again, use `this.client` instead. You are never mutating data in React/Redux, so you can't use old references.

Comment: @ksenia You're welcome. Consider upvoting  and [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if you feel any of the answers worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this =)

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  client: { 
    abilities: [ ...this.prevState.abilitiesDisplay ]
  }
}));
```

I assume that you don't want to keep the old values in the abilities by your information above.

Answer (score 0):

You need `this.state.abilitiesDisplay`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?